# Dojo Dijit Claro Theme disable mouse over

Tags: dojo

I´ve been trying to change the Dojo Claro theme because it´s too light and i wanted to get rid of some of the efects.
One of them is the mouse over of form dijits.
Is there any way to disable, in general, the effect of the mouse over in Buttons and inputs like textboxes, filtering selects etc.....
I cannot catch the css on firebug when the mouse is 'overing' that elements. There should be a class that it´s appended to the element that produces that effect.
can anyone tell what it is?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the **Simple-Enabled-Button** on the **Basic Form Widgets** tab of the theme tester - http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.7.0/dojo-release-1.7.0/dijit/themes/themeTester.html?theme=claro.

No hover:

```
<span class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitButton" role="presentation" widgetid="dijit_form_Button_1">
    <span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonNode" data-dojo-attach-event="ondijitclick:_onClick" role="presentation">
        <span class="dijitReset dijitStretch dijitButtonContents" data-dojo-attach-point="titleNode,focusNode" role="button" aria-labelledby="dijit_form_Button_1_label" tabindex="0" id="dijit_form_Button_1">
            <span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitIcon dijitIconTask" data-dojo-attach-point="iconNode"></span>
            <span class="dijitReset dijitToggleButtonIconChar">?</span>
            <span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonText" id="dijit_form_Button_1_label" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode">Simple</span>
        </span>
    </span>
    <input type="button" value="" class="dijitOffScreen" tabindex="-1" role="presentation" data-dojo-attach-point="valueNode">
</span>
```

Hover:

```
<span class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitButton dijitButtonHover dijitHover" role="presentation" widgetid="dijit_form_Button_1">
    <span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonNode" data-dojo-attach-event="ondijitclick:_onClick" role="presentation">
        <span class="dijitReset dijitStretch dijitButtonContents" data-dojo-attach-point="titleNode,focusNode" role="button" aria-labelledby="dijit_form_Button_1_label" tabindex="0" id="dijit_form_Button_1">
            <span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitIcon dijitIconTask" data-dojo-attach-point="iconNode"></span>
            <span class="dijitReset dijitToggleButtonIconChar">?</span>
            <span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonText" id="dijit_form_Button_1_label" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode">Simple</span>
        </span>
    </span>
    <input type="button" value="" class="dijitOffScreen" tabindex="-1" role="presentation" data-dojo-attach-point="valueNode">
</span>
```

Identical apart from the outer span's classes ...

No hover:

```
dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitButton
```

Hover:

```
dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitButton dijitButtonHover dijitHover
```

The other form fields may differ, but you'll have to take a look at those. From what little I've looked, I think each form dijit has its own hover class(es).

`dijitHover` appears to be a functional class, rather than a UI class, as I can't find it in the Dojo 1.8.3 css or JS:

```
d:\dev\js\dojo-release-1.8.3>findstr /i/s "dijithover" *.css
FINDSTR: // ignored

d:\dev\js\dojo-release-1.8.3>findstr /i/s "dijithover" *.js
FINDSTR: // ignored
```

but I can find `dijitButtonHover`:

```
d:\dev\js\dojo-release-1.8.3>findstr /i/s "dijitbuttonhover" *.css
FINDSTR: // ignored
dijit\themes\claro\claro.css:.claro .dijitButtonHover .dijitButtonNode,
dijit\themes\claro\claro.css:.dj_ie .claro .dijitToolbar .dijitButtonHover .dijitButtonNode,
dijit\themes\claro\claro.css:.claro .dijitToolbar .dijitButtonHover .dijitButtonNode,
dijit\themes\claro\form\Button.css:.claro .dijitButtonHover .dijitButtonNode,
dijit\themes\claro\Toolbar.css:.dj_ie .claro .dijitToolbar .dijitButtonHover .dijitButtonNode,
dijit\themes\claro\Toolbar.css:.claro .dijitToolbar .dijitButtonHover .dijitButtonNode,
dijit\themes\nihilo\form\Button.css:.nihilo .dijitButtonHover .dijitButtonNode,
dijit\themes\nihilo\nihilo.css:.nihilo .dijitButtonHover .dijitButtonNode,
dijit\themes\nihilo\nihilo.css:.nihilo .dijitToolbar .dijitButtonHover,
dijit\themes\nihilo\Toolbar.css:.nihilo .dijitToolbar .dijitButtonHover,
dijit\themes\soria\form\Button.css:.soria .dijitButtonHover .dijitButtonNode,
dijit\themes\soria\soria.css:.soria .dijitButtonHover .dijitButtonNode,
dijit\themes\soria\soria.css:.soria .dijitToolbar .dijitButtonHover,
dijit\themes\soria\Toolbar.css:.soria .dijitToolbar .dijitButtonHover,
dijit\themes\tundra\form\Button.css:.tundra .dijitButtonHover .dijitButtonNode,
dijit\themes\tundra\Toolbar.css:.tundra .dijitToolbar .dijitButtonHover,
dijit\themes\tundra\tundra.css:.tundra .dijitButtonHover .dijitButtonNode,
dijit\themes\tundra\tundra.css:.tundra .dijitToolbar .dijitButtonHover,
dojox\grid\enhanced\resources\claro\EnhancedGrid.css:.dijitButtonHover .dojoxGridFBarCloseBtnIcon {
dojox\grid\enhanced\resources\claro\EnhancedGrid.css:.dijitButtonHover .dojoxGridFCBoxRemoveCBoxBtnIcon {
dojox\grid\enhanced\resources\claro\EnhancedGrid.css:.dijitButtonHover .dojoxGridFStatusTipDelRuleBtnIcon {
dojox\grid\enhanced\resources\claro\EnhancedGrid.css:.claro .dojoxGridFBarInfoTD .dojoxGridFBarClearFilterBtn.dijitButtonHover .dijitButtonText {
dojox\grid\enhanced\resources\claro\Filter.css:.claro .dojoxGridFBarInfoTD .dojoxGridFBarClearFilterBtn.dijitButtonHover .dijitButtonText {
dojox\grid\enhanced\resources\claroEnhancedGrid.css:.dijitButtonHover .dojoxGridFBarCloseBtnIcon {
dojox\grid\enhanced\resources\claroEnhancedGrid.css:.dijitButtonHover .dojoxGridFCBoxRemoveCBoxBtnIcon {
dojox\grid\enhanced\resources\claroEnhancedGrid.css:.dijitButtonHover .dojoxGridFStatusTipDelRuleBtnIcon {
dojox\grid\enhanced\resources\claroEnhancedGrid.css:.claro .dojoxGridFBarInfoTD .dojoxGridFBarClearFilterBtn.dijitButtonHover .dijitButtonText {
dojox\grid\enhanced\resources\EnhancedGrid.css:.dijitButtonHover .dojoxGridFBarCloseBtnIcon {
dojox\grid\enhanced\resources\EnhancedGrid.css:.dijitButtonHover .dojoxGridFCBoxRemoveCBoxBtnIcon {
dojox\grid\enhanced\resources\EnhancedGrid.css:.dijitButtonHover .dojoxGridFStatusTipDelRuleBtnIcon {
dojox\grid\enhanced\resources\Filter.css:.dijitButtonHover .dojoxGridFBarCloseBtnIcon {
dojox\grid\enhanced\resources\Filter.css:.dijitButtonHover .dojoxGridFCBoxRemoveCBoxBtnIcon {
dojox\grid\enhanced\resources\Filter.css:.dijitButtonHover .dojoxGridFStatusTipDelRuleBtnIcon {
dojox\grid\enhanced\resources\tundra\EnhancedGrid.css:.dijitButtonHover .dojoxGridFBarCloseBtnIcon {
dojox\grid\enhanced\resources\tundra\EnhancedGrid.css:.dijitButtonHover .dojoxGridFCBoxRemoveCBoxBtnIcon {
dojox\grid\enhanced\resources\tundra\EnhancedGrid.css:.dijitButtonHover .dojoxGridFStatusTipDelRuleBtnIcon {
dojox\grid\enhanced\resources\tundraEnhancedGrid.css:.dijitButtonHover .dojoxGridFBarCloseBtnIcon {
dojox\grid\enhanced\resources\tundraEnhancedGrid.css:.dijitButtonHover .dojoxGridFCBoxRemoveCBoxBtnIcon {
dojox\grid\enhanced\resources\tundraEnhancedGrid.css:.dijitButtonHover .dojoxGridFStatusTipDelRuleBtnIcon {
dojox\layout\resources\RotatorContainer.css:.rotatorIcons .dijitButtonHover .previous{background-position:0 -16px;}
dojox\layout\resources\RotatorContainer.css:.rotatorIcons .dijitButtonHover .next{background-position:-16px -16px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dojo buttons have 3 hierarchical layers of Html SPAN nodes.
Whenever the mouse enters the button, only the top SPAN is changed. Two CSS classes are appended: "dijitButtonHover" and "dijitHover" (as you show in your "No hover" and "hover" HTML markup). 
To change the Dojo Claro to your own design when the mouse enters the button, try the CSS selector:

```
.claro .dijitReset.dijitInline.dijitButton.dijitButtonHover{}
```

This may not work if you have in your CSS stylesheet other selectors with a higher specific weight. If this is the case, add some of your CSS classes to the above selector, in order to increase its weight.